# Transform text to vector shape in Adobe Flash Professional CS5

Tags: flash-cs4

How? Question is simple, hope the answer will be as well.

Comment: was the text created in flash ? or imported ? if it was created in flash, then its allready vector ( with the text tool ). if it was not, then you need to bitmap trace it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use the text tool <kbd>T</kbd> and type
- Select the text with the Selection tool <kbd>V</kbd>
- From the menu select `Modify` then `Break Apart` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>
- Finally use the Subselection tool <kbd>A</kbd> and click the text edge (no the inside fill), you'll see the cursor change to an arrow with a black dot.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do it using actoinscript?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze I've looked around and unfortunately the answer is no. This question is related http://forums.adobe.com/message/3219417

Answer (score 2):

If it was imported, as @Dementic says, you'll need [to trace it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7e9ca.html) using *Modify > Bitmap > Trace Bitmap*.

If you [created it in Flash using the Text Tool](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-flash-professional-cs5/gs11-using-the-text-tool-to-create-tlf-text/), then it is already in a vector format. If you created the file using a newer/older version of Flash that the default/only option is [*Classic Text*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7d50a.html) whereas for CS5 the default is the *TLF* format introduced in that version. If you're not sure about the difference between *TLF* and *Classic Text*, [Andy Anderson can explain](http://infiniteskills.com/blog/2011/04/adobe-flash-cs5-tutorial-classic-versus-cs5-text/).

Reading between the lines of your concise question you're probably trying to break apart *Classic Text*, [so here's how](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7d2ca.html).